# TextInput cursor automatically moves to front when it regains focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this really weird behavior..

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
DOWN = 40;
UP = 38;

$(document).on("keydown", "#text_input", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == DOWN) {
        $("#list").focus();
    }
});

$(document).on("keydown", "#list", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == UP) {
        $("#text_input").focus();
    }
});
```

So basically, if the user hits DOWN key while "#text_input" has focus, the focus shifts to the "#list".
In turn, when the user has focus on "#list" and then hits UP key, "#text_input" regains its focus.

This works fine, EXCEPT the cursor in the "#text_input" automatically moves to the front of the text value when it regains focus. I want to prevent this so that the user can continue typing from where he left off before switching focus to the "#list."

I searched on Stackoverflow to find a way to move the cursor to the end of the text input, and found this solution:

```
$(document).on("focus", "#text_input", function() {

    value = $("#text_input").val();
    $("#text_input").val("");
    $("#text_input").val(value);

});
```

This actually did move the cursor to the end ONLY WHEN I switched focus using the Mouse event. For example, when I CLICKed on the blank part of the page and then RECLICKed the "#text_input," the cursor did move to the end of the input.

However, strangely enough, this does not work when I regain focus by using my function, namely Pressing the DOWN key and then the UP key. The cursor still moves to the front of the textfield.

Sorry for making the question confusing,, but this is the best I can do :((

Does anyone know why this is occurring and any possible solution??

Thanks!!!

PS

**Just added it to JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jakeaustin5574/AU9CA/3/

Comment: Do you mean the text is being *selected*?

Comment: @Italy hmm... I guess? I mean when the text field is highlighted.. In other words, while user has focus on the text field so that he can type on it.

Comment: Please upload your problem to http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Italy SURE, just a minute!

Comment: Don't forget to add the link to the jsFiddle to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are almost here.. change your code to be:

```
$(document).on("focus", "#text_input", function() {

    value = $("#text_input").val();
    $("#text_input").val("");
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("#text_input").val(value);
    }, 0);

});
```

If that doesnt fix it, id like to see it on jsfiddle

Comment: Maybe it's simpler to write: `$("#text_input").val("").delay(1).val(value)`. Also it'll be simpler to use the `$("#text_input").focus(etc..)`

Comment: delay is for animations. its news to me that it works with `val. Does it ? ;)